# Rails 3 - notice and error flash cannot be rendered in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, partial

I was trying to clean up `application.html.erb`, by moving parts of the layout into partials.  I had the following code for handling flash errors/notifications:

```
<div id="flash">
  <% if flash[:notice] %>
    <h3 class="info_box"><%= flash[:notice] %></h3>
  <% end %>
  <% if flash[:error] %>
    <h3 class="error_box"><%= flash[:error] %></h3>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

This code worked fine in `application.html.erb`, until I moved it into a file called "`_flash.html.erb`" and replaced it with the following:

```
<%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
```

In the partial the flash hash was not a recognized object and causes a "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" error.

I've move the code back to application.html.erb and all is good.  But I couldn't find an answer for accessing the flash hash within a partial.  Looking at the Rails Guide for "Rendering and Layouts" I can see that there are various ways for `render()` to pass variables into the partial, but I was unsuccessful in figuring it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `<%= render :partial => 'layouts/flash' %>` ? Also, where are you calling this `render` from ? And keep that partial out of layouts I would say.

Comment: You could definitely provide local variables to the partial like this: `render 'layouts/flash, :locals => {:flash => flash}`. But I don't know if this is really the best option.

Comment: Zabba and Topek - thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately neither work.  Both suggestions lead to: "You have a nil object..."  This really is perplexing!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Goliatone's solution seemed to work, but in the end it didn't.  I found out that the reason this was not working for me was that I had named my partial `_flash`.  Apparently Rails creates a local variable for the partial using the partial's name (without the `"_"` character.)  So I had a variable clash.  As soon as I change the name of the partial to something other than `_flash` everything worked perfectly.  I found the answer here:  [Rails flash[:notice] always nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972084/rails-flashnotice-always-nil)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the conditional check for flash in the layout, and if it exists then render the partial:

```
<%= render 'layouts/flash' unless flash.nil?%>
```

Then, if it exists it will get rendered as expected.

Comment: Thanks goliatone!  This works great, but it is confusing to me.  Ruby/Rails does not issue a nil-object error for "if flash[:notice]" while it is in application.html.erb, but when "if flash[:notice]" is in a partial, it will issue a nil-object error!  Very strange!  Why is that?

Comment: flash is an Object  *<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000004d1f278 @used=#<Set: {:notice}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=nil>*   ... so it won't be nil.. even if no flash message