# how to pass key value through [action].js.erb remote: true ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is how I display my flash messages using key value.

```
application_html.erb
<div class="container-fluid">    
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>" data-turbolinks="false">
    <a class="close lay" data-dismiss="alert">&#215</a>
      <% if message.is_a?(String) %>
        <div id="flash_<%=message_type%>">
          <%= sanitize(message) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>  
   </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Now I have in my controller:

```
def saved 
  ...
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js
  end
end
```

And in my form:

```
<%= link_to... remote: true, method: :put %>
```

Now in my saved.js.erb file, I have the following:

```
<% if request.put? %>
  <% response = current_user.saved_articles.new(article: @article) %>
  <% if !response.valid? %>
    FLASH SOMETHING HERE
  <% else %>
    <% response.save %>
    FLASH SOMETHING HERE
  <% end %>    
<% else request.delete? %>
  <% current_user.saveds.delete(@article) %>
  FLASH SOMETHING HERE 
<% end %>
```

How do I pass notice: "You have saved this article" and notice: "You have unsaved this article" ?

Comment: One way to do is create a js function which temporarily adds a div(the one which you have in `application.html.erb`) and then fades it away. Call that js function in **saved.js.erb**, have a type field in that function by which you add a class success or danger for different types of flash messages. This helps because you use this function globally across your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `saved` action actually saving? if you're saving a record (or updating or deleting) you should (don't have to) do this using `create` and `update` and `destroy` actions. Put everything into one action isn't the proper way to do it, even when you're manipulating db records... why not proper CRUD:

```
def create
  # create logic
  render js: { model: @your_model, status: @your_model.persisted? : :ok, :unprocessable_entity }
end

(and other actions)
```

and then in your js, you can ask the async call status, and build the messaging from there.

Answer (score 1):

Store the flash message component in a partial and call it in **js.erb** file, remove it after few seconds if you wish to do so.

One small note if you plan to name the partial as **_flash.html.erb**, flash object value would become nil in the partial's:

> I found out that the reason this was not working for me was that I had
>   named my partial *flash. Apparently Rails creates a local variable for
>   the partial using the partial's name (without the "*" character.) So I
>   had a variable clash. As soon as I change the name of the partial to
>   something other than _flash everything worked perfectly. [I found the
>   answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972084/rails-flashnotice-always-nil): Rails flash[:notice] always nil

*-from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8890048/3863146)*

#### application_html.erb:

```
<div class="container-fluid">    
  <%= render partial: 'shared/flash_messages' %>
</div>
```

#### shared/_flash_messages.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %> flash_messages" data-turbolinks="false">
    <a class="close lay" data-dismiss="alert">&#215</a>
      <% if message.is_a?(String) %>
        <div id="flash_<%=message_type%>">
          <%= sanitize(message) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>  
   </div>
<% end %>
```

#### controller.rb

```
def saved 
  if saved?
    flash[:success] = "You have saved this article"
  else 
    flash[:danger] = "You have unsaved this article"
  end
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js
  end
end
```

#### saved.js.erb

```
    <% if request.put? %>
      <% response = current_user.saved_articles.new(article: @article) %>
      <% if !response.valid? %>
        // append to any element
        $('body').append('<%= j render partial: "shared/flash_messages"%>').fadeOut(2000, function(){
   $('.flash_messages').remove();
});
      <% else %>
        <% response.save %>
        $('body').append('<%= j render partial: "shared/flash_messages"%>').fadeOut(2000, function(){
   $('.flash_messages').remove();
});
      <% end %>    
    <% else request.delete? %>
      <% current_user.saveds.delete(@article) %>
      $('body').append('<%= j render partial: "shared/flash_messages"%>').fadeOut(2000, function(){
   $('.flash_messages').remove();
});
    <% end %>
```